# Examples for geodesic balls which are not convex

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to imagine normal balls which are not convex. **Are there any nice exmaples?**

Obviously, in the Euclidean space all normal balls are convex and it seems to me this is also true for the sphere.

Perhaps a space of negative curvature? (Is there a necessary condition on the curvature for the existence of non-convex normal balls?)

---

**Reminders:**

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. A *normal ball* around $p$, is a set of the form of $\exp_p(B_r(0))$ where $\bar B_r(0)$ (the closed ball in $T_pM$ with radius $r$) is contained in an open set $V \subseteq T_pM$ such that $\exp_p:V \to \exp_p(V)$ is a diffeomorphism.

A subset $A \subseteq M$ is *convex*, if every two points in $A$ can be joined by a minimizing geodesic (Some people call this *weak convexity* I think, since I do not require uniqueness).

Comment: In the round unit sphere, a geodesic ball of radius greater than $\pi/2$, which compactly contains a closed hemisphere, is not geodesically convex.

Comment: True! Ok, this is nice, but this only works for "large" balls (I was implicitly thinking on small balls). Is it true (in general) that every sufficiently small ball is convex?

Comment: Sufficiently small geodesic balls in a Riemannian manifold are convex, see e.g., [Are small $\varepsilon$-balls convex in geodesic metric spaces?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252605) at MathOverflow.

Comment: Thanks! I looked for something like this but did not googled the right words it seems... I will probably delete the question then.

Comment: (That upvote signifies "glad you found an answer". :)

Comment: A manifold is locally Euclidean by definition. If Riemannian manifolds are manifolds, then, it would necessarily be locally Euclidean, and so anything that's true in Euclidean space is true in a small enough ball on the manifold.

Comment: @dejongbrent This is not true: Riemannian manifolds are localy Euclidean "topologically", but not metrically. They can have non-zero curvature, and in that case they are not locally *isometric* to Euclidean balls, only locally homeomorphic.

Comment: @AsafShachar OK, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The question turned out to be rather easy, I am posting an answer based on Andrew D. Hwang's comments.

In the round unit sphere, a geodesic ball of radius greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$
, which compactly contains a closed hemisphere, is not geodesically convex.

Also, as [stated here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252605/are-small-varepsilon-balls-convex-in-geodesic-metric-spaces), sufficiently small geodesic balls in a Riemannian manifold are convex.

Comment: Have you a reference for the fact stated in the link you gave?