# Are the convex open balls always a base?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. I define a set $\mathcal{U} \subseteq X$ to be convex if for all $x,z \in \mathcal{U}$ and $y \in X$ we have
$$d(x,y) + d(y,z) = d(x,z) \implies y \in \mathcal{U}$$
An open ball in $(X, d)$ may not be convex and an example of this is a ball in $S^1$ (equipped with the "shortest arc length" metric) with a radius greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Nevertheless, the convex open balls in $S^1$ are a base for the topology induced by the metric.

**Are the convex open balls in $(X,d)$ always a base for the topology induced by $d$?**

These questions/answers may be relevant:

- [Examples for geodesic balls which are not convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068691/examples-for-geodesic-balls-which-are-not-convex)
- [Are small $\varepsilon$-balls convex in geodesic metric spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252605/are-small-varepsilon-balls-convex-in-geodesic-metric-spaces)

But I am not sure whether the notion of convexity in use is equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: no non-empty open set in this metric space is convex in your sense.

Let $D=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, and let $X=D^{\Bbb N}$, the Cartesian product of countably infinitely many copies of $D$, so that the elements of $X$ are the sequences $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that each $x_n$ is either $0$ or $1$. (This space is homeomorphic to the well-known [middle-thirds Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).)

For distinct $x,y\in X$ let $\delta(x,y)=\min\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\ne y_n\}$, the first index at which $x$ and $y$ disagree; then

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=y\\
2^{-\delta(x,y)},&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

is a metric on $X$. Suppose that $x,y$, and $z$ are distinct points of $X$ and that $d(x,y)+d(y,z)=d(x,z)$; then

$$2^{-\delta(x,y)}+2^{-\delta(y,z)}=2^{-\delta(x,z)}\,.\tag{1}$$

Let $n=\max\{\delta(x,y),\delta(y,z),\delta(x,z)\}$; clearly $\delta(x,y),\delta(y,z)>\delta(x,z)$, so we may assume that $n=\delta(x,y)$. Let $k=\delta(y,z)\le n$ and $\ell=\delta(x,z)<k$. Then we can rewrite $(1)$ as $2^{-n}+2^{-k}=2^{-\ell}$, and after dividing through by $2^{-n}$ we have

$$1+2^{n-k}=2^{n-\ell}\,.$$

Clearly this is possible if and only if $2^{n-k}=1$ and $2^{n-\ell}=2$, i.e., iff $k=n$ and $\ell=n-1$. Since $k=n$, we know that $x_i=y_i=z_i$ for $i<n$ and $x_n\ne y_n\ne z_n$. But then $x_n=z_n$, so $x_i=z_i$ for $i\le n$, and $n-1=\ell=\delta(x,z)\ge n+1$, which is absurd.

Thus, for $x,y,z\in X$ the relation $d(x,y)+d(y,z)=d(x,z)$ holds iff $y\in\{x,z\}$, so the only convex sets in $X$ are the singletons and doubletons. Every non-empty open set in $X$ is infinite (and in fact has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$), so $\langle X,d\rangle$ does not have a base of convex sets.

Comment: does it make sense to say that a "locally convex" metric space is one which has a base of convex sets (as in above)?

Comment: @ThomasKing: I don’t know; it would probably depend on what you want to be able to do with the property.

Comment: I was just wondering how you would get around the fact that discrete spaces (such as graphs and lattices) exhibit "convex" subspaces that are not convex in the usual sense (i.e. there is always another point between two points) - thinking about it, "locally" isn't the right word here

Comment: @ThomasKing: It would really depend on what I was trying to do, and since my topological interests have always lain in other directions, I don’t even have any sense of what might be possible, interesting, or useful.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway for the great counter example!

Comment: @ThomasKing: You’re welcome! Sorry that I can’t be more helpful.